# Looping through a list to generate pixel heights taking long time

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to loop though a list of urls and trying to extract their pixel lengths.
For a limited set of urls this loop works great. But fr a higher number of urls ( 50k urls in the list ) This loop is very slow. Is there a faster way of looping or way of optimizing the loop: Also, Is it the javascript snippet which is slowing down the for loop ? If so is there a way to improve its performance?

Here is my code :

```
# loop through the URLs
for url in tqdm.tqdm(urls):
    # execute the JavaScript code using the webdriver instance
    driver.get(url)
    section_pixels = driver.execute_script("""
        var cumu = 0;
        var secAttr = 'data-analytics-section-engagement';
        sections = document.querySelectorAll("["+secAttr+"]");
        const section_width = [];
        for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            if (window.getComputedStyle(sections[i]).display != 'none') {
                cumu = cumu + sections[i].offsetHeight;
                var section_nme = sections[i].getAttribute(secAttr);
                var offsetheight = sections[i].offsetHeight;
                var final_val = section_nme.concat(' *pixels: ',offsetheight);
                section_width.push(final_val);
            }
        }
        return section_width;
    """)
    
    # print the individual heights for the current URL , just put the console log in the list will remove the cumulative    
    for i in section_pixels:
        x=i.split('*')[0]
        y=x.split(':')[1]
        u=i.split('*')[1]
        v=u.split(':')[1]
        final_string=" # ".join([url,y,v])
        cleaned_string_list.append(final_string)
        url_list.append(url)
    df=pd.DataFrame(cleaned_string_list)
# quit the webdriver instance
driver.quit()
```

Here is the output I am getting :

```
Output: 
                      url                    section_name pixel_height
0  https://www.apple.com             hero-iphone-14-pro            704
1  https://www.apple.com                 hero-iphone-14            748
2  https://www.apple.com      hero-apple-watch-series-8            748
3  https://www.apple.com          promo-wwdc23-announce            636
4  https://www.apple.com                     promo-ipad            636
5  https://www.apple.com    promo-macbook-pro-14-and-16            636
6  https://www.apple.com                  promo-homepod            636
7  https://www.apple.com     promo-airpods-pro-campaign            636
8  https://www.apple.com               promo-apple-card            636
9  https://www.apple.com                tv-plus-gallery            561
```

[image]

As you can see iterations per second is very low for this for loop.